# TypeError: feature is not a function in discord.js using WOK tutorials

Tags: discord.js, typeerror

Coding DJS bot using the WOK YT tutorials as a base.

Refactored all my code and made a load-features file to load many of my commands into index.js automatically.

Here is the code for that file:

```js
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = (client) => {
    const readFeatures = (dir) => {
        const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir));
        for (const file of files) {
            const stat = fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname, dir, file));
            if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                readFeatures(path.join(dir, file));
            } else if (file !== "load-features.js") {
                const feature = require(path.join(__dirname, dir, file));
                console.log(`Enabling feature "${file}"`);
                feature(client);
            }
        }
    };

    readFeatures(".");
};
```

The error says `TypeError: feature is not a function` when calling `feature(client)`. It was working fine yesterday but suddenly decided not to work.

If you need more examples of the code itself, here is a link to the tutorial repository, where this file is identical to mine and how it is connected to index.js: https://github.com/AlexzanderFlores/Worn-Off-Keys-Discord-Js/tree/master/43-Refactoring

Please advise.

Comment: Are there files in the directory that doesn't export a function?

Comment: The bot stops after running through the levels.js file which is commented out...

Here is the code for levels.js:
https://sourceb.in/NtGahNDdZe

Next files are:
membercount: https://sourceb.in/dxGf6ajoLL
message-counter: https://sourceb.in/ajhe1ibbNF
mute: https://sourceb.in/KNrQ6HZpID
poll: https://sourceb.in/FtnbXMUOfE
role-claim: https://sourceb.in/69CzYB4bG2
scaling-channels: https://sourceb.in/LAxREgnzmR
welcome: https://sourceb.in/RJ5hMFT2uj

levels commented cuz level dont update when XP reaches new level
membercount because wrong commands
mute cuz changing it later

Comment: Since levels.js is effectively empty requiring it would return undefined. `feature` would therefore be undefined and undefined is apparently not a function.